# How to replace a matching pattern inside a file to another using bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

My script has many lines starting with slo. How can I replace all the strings that are starting with slo to fwd using bash commands? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is a snippet of my script

```
template_version: 2018-03-02

resources:

  instance01:
    type: ../../../templates/nf.yaml
    properties:
      vm_name: 'slol2lvdl1'
      vm_flavour: 'dns_19te'
      image_name: 'pdns_dnsd_slo_211214121207'
      vm_az: 'az-1'
      vm_disk_root_size: '50'
      vm_disk_data_size: '50'
      network_mgmt_refs: 'int:dns_ox_slo_507:c3dns_slo_live_nc_vnns_pcg'
```

My requirement is to replace all slo to fwd in the above code. I have 5 files like this in the same directory.

Comment: Is `sed -i 's/slo/fwd/g' file.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt` sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is the go-to for file content replacements with regular expressions.  If every `slo` you want to replace is between `_` characters it's fairly easy with  a command like this (in GNU sed which ships with just about all linuxes):

```
sed -i -e 's/_slo_/_fwd_/g' files to replace
```

`-i` replaces the text *inline*, replacing existing file contents with updated contents.

If not all `slo` are within `_` characters you need to worry about unintentional matches.

Be sure to make a backup of these files or if they're in a git repo work from a clean state in case you don't like the change.  Using `git` to track the changes might make sense even if you don't currently have the files in a git repo as this will make it trivial to compare before and after.

Answer (score -1):

sed -i 's/slo/fwd/'  worked! Also found many alternatives but sed was straight forward!